# Google Maps Autocomplete not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Here is the function:

```
function initializeMap(){
        var LatLng = {lat: 20.23, lng: -8.28460};
        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 6,
            scrollwheel:false
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                title: "Binko"
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('accommodation_address');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds',map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',function(){
            var place=autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry){
                return;
            }
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }

            marker.setPlace( ({
                placeId: place.place_id,
                location: place.geometry.location
            }));
        });
    };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

I get the uncaught type error, saying autocomplete is not defined, even though I included the library. My API call looks like this:
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places">

Comment: Your code as posted works for me (but it isn't complete). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 13):

I have had similar problem. Google maps and autocomplete has worked on my old websites and on localhost but not on new website. I had to create api key and include it in code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Then I had in developer console (where I have got api key) to enable additional api. Steps:

1. select your project
2. in left API Manager menu click on Overview
3. find Google Places API Web Service(you can type it to search box or find it between Google Maps API)
4. click on Google Places API Web Service
5. click on Enable button

Comment: Spent the whole evening trying to figure the enigma. Wonder how many people figured it out right from the start that `Places` API needs to be manually enabled.

Comment: I didn't get it off the bat thats for sure!

Comment: I literally have been going crazy trying to figure this our for two days! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Well, there went two hours of work. At least I got it fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initializeMap" async defer></script>
```

instead of

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

maybe `Places` library is not loaded

Comment: How could it not be loaded, &libraries=places is right there?

Hmm, I tried your solution, unfortunately it leaves me without any map at all :(

Comment: try to use with `async` and `defer` attributes in `script` tag. I edited example

Comment: Still not working, and now it says I inculded the google maps api multiple times...

Comment: Remove all your own code and insert this one to escape multiple loading :) I just want to understand there is mistake, it has to be very simple.

Comment: Is google maps still loading multiple times? is something happened?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no problem with your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm>
<head>
    <title>
    Map
    </title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en" ></script>
    <script>
    function initializeMap(){
        var LatLng = {lat: 20.23, lng: -8.28460};
        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 6,
            scrollwheel:false,
            noClear: true
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                title: "Binko"
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('accommodation_address');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds',map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',function(){
            var place=autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry){
                return;
            }
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }

            marker.setPlace( ({
                placeId: place.place_id,
                location: place.geometry.location
            }));
        });
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #accommodation_address {
      width: 20%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 10%;
      top: 10%;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">
  <input type="text" id="accommodation_address" />
</div>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: That's weird. I have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had my API key enabled, but what I was missing was `&libraries=places` in the API key include. Documented:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places